# Is it possible to simplify this H_bridge circuit to only 4 transistors?

Tags: motor, h-bridge

I would like to control a simple DC 0.4A/6V motor with both directions. I use a simple circuit that generates a rectangular signal with equal duty cycle to control the directions of the motor. I used the H-Bridge mode based on 4 Darlington transistors. Two extra transistors work as inverters - to control the signal when it equals "0". Can it be simplified?
[image]

Comment: Are PNP or MOSFETs an option here?

Answer (score 5):

It's a badly efficient and ineffective circuit for controlling a DC motor at low voltage. Each of the lower Darlingtons will drop about 1 volt between collector and emitter when conducting; that's a loss of 1 volt that the motor just won't ever get.

The upper Darlingtons are a tad worse because they are emitter followers and, they'll drop maybe 1.5 volts each when conducting so, if your motor is 6 volts and your supply is 5 volts, the motor will only see about 2.5 volts under full load in either direction.

> *Is it possible to simplify this H_bridge circuit to only 4
> transistors?*

Given that it's a poor design to begin with, it's unlikely to be worth the effort. I suggest starting with N-channel MOSFET in the lower half and P-channel MOSFETs in the upper half to get something like a half decent performance then, come back and ask the same question.